# find command outputs files without a directory structure

Tags: find, directory, tar

I want to tar some Python files and send it across a server. I do:

```
find /some/path -iname "*.py"  -exec tar czfv python_files.tar {} +
```

Followed by:

```
pv python_files.tar| ssh some_user@some_server 'cat | tar xz -C /some/path/on/server'
```

Unfortunately when I SSH on the server I see the *full* directory structure has been sent across the server and I find my python files like that:

```
/some/path/on/server/complicated/sub/directory/some_file.py
/some/path/on/server/another/complicated/sub/directory/some_file2.py
```

What I want is my files to be at the root:

```
 /some/path/on/server/some_file.py
 /some/path/on/server/some_file2.py
```

What is the missing piece?

Comment: What do you want to do when you have files with the same name in different subfolders?

Answer (score 3):

as per man tar (a long reading)

> --transform=EXPRESSION, --xform=EXPRESSION
>
>   Use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names.

I used

```
find . -name \*.py -print | xargs tar cf tmp7/test-py.tar --transform=s:./.*/:: -
```

all files were on same level.

## sed expression

- `s:./.*/::` : (greedy) replace `./.*/` by nothing.

## bonus:

```
find . -name \*.py -print | sed -e s:./.*/:: | awk 'a[$1]++ { print ; }'
```

will print dupplicate filename.

Answer (score 1):

Like the solution from user Archemar, only applied when extracting the tar. Substituting `.*/` with the empty string.

```
pv python_files.tar| ssh some_user@some_server 'cat | tar xz --transform=s,.*/,, -C /some/path/on/server'
```